# JSoup can't find Element

Tags: java, jsoup

Im trying to find an Element with JSoup (and the Parent of the Element should get deleted) but it's not working for some reason.

This is what im searching for = https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5rp1.png

And I tried

```
Elements test = doc.select(":containsOwn( Members)");
Elements test = doc.select(":contains( Members)");
Elements test = doc.select("div:containsOwn( Members)");
Elements test = doc.select("div:contains( Members)");
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```
String test = doc.select(":contains(Members)").first().text();
```